# loop through a filtered range excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to highlight cells when there are 3 or more with the same value, I have the bellow code but it isn't working right because it loop twice into each range. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```
Sub HighlightCells()
Dim k As Integer, myCounter As Integer, firstRow As Integer
Dim myClientExport As Worksheet, myTemplate As Variant
Dim vRange As Range, myRange As Range 
Dim myAddr As String

Set myClientExport = Excel.ActiveSheet 
Set vRange = myClientExport.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 


firstRow = vRange.Areas(2).Rows(1).Row
myAddr = Cells(firstRow, 4).Value
myCounter = 0
For Each myRange In vRange.Rows 
    k = myRange.Row

    If k > firstRow Then
        If myAddr = Cells(k, 4).Value Then
            myCounter = myCounter + 1
        Else
            myAddr = Cells(k, 4).Value
            myCounter = 0
        End If
        Select Case myCounter
            Case 3

                For i = 0 To 2
                    OId = Cells(k - i, 1).Value
                 Next i
                Cells(k, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                Cells(k - 1, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                Cells(k - 2, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
            Case Is > 3
                Cells(k, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End Select
    End If
Next myRange
End Sub
```

[My data unfiltered look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyMw7.jpg)

[My data filtered look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqSKo.jpg)

I want to highlight all Address with 3 or more Active order status.

Comment: you may want to add some examples of how your data (filtered and unfiltered) look like

Comment: It's hard to follow the logic of your code, please load a screen-shot sample of your data and desired result

Comment: Thank you, I just added a sample of may data unfiltered and filtered.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your code to work. Right off I get "Application-defined or object-defined" run-time error on `firstRow = vRange.Areas(2).Rows(1).Row`.

So what I did is a CountIf formula in column E:
`=COUNTIF(D$2:D$7,D2)` then set Conditional Formatting. If the range is dynamic, use VBA to determine limits and propagate the formula and Conditional Formatting. Something like:

```
Dim rCount As Integer
rCount = Range("D1", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("D2:D" & rCount).Select
Selection.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$E2=3"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Range("E2:E" & rCount).Select
Selection.Formula = "=CountIf($D$2:$D$" & rCount & ", $D2)"
```

Comment: Oh I don't get any error on it, but it doesn't do what I need. Your code don't solve it, I'm working on a filtered range. I added in the original post a sample of my data unfiltered an filtered, maybe that can give you a better idea about what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Tested my code on filtered rows and as far as I can tell, it works. The hidden records are ignored and the output fits your example.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't works. It's close, but, it take only the visible records to be counted, however on each counter of those visible records include the records hidden that match. That means if one of the visible records has 1 rows visible and 2 hidden, your code counts 3 and highlight that record when really it should not be considers. I'll figure out if I can modify it to bring me exactly what I need. Thank you so much, your code is a possible way.

Comment: Interesting, wonder how I was getting it to ignore hidden rows on initial tests? Did a quick search and apparently doing a count that ignores hidden rows requires a custom function and looks complicated, which is essentially what you are attempting with your code. Sorry.

Comment: It's fine, for now I'll add a temporal sheet with the filtered data and do there what I need and delete it later, because is complicated dealing with filtered data. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this to see if that works for you.
The code will place a CountIFs formula in column F and delete it in the end.
You may tweak the code as per your requirement.

```
Sub HighlightFilteredCells()
Dim sws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim cell As Range
Set sws = Sheets("Sheet1")
If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
sws.Range("F2:F" & lr).Formula = "=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$" & lr & ",D2,$E$2:$E$" & lr & ",""Active"")"
sws.Columns(5).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
With sws.Rows(1)
    .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="Active"
    If sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
        For Each cell In sws.Range("F2:F" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If cell.Value >= 3 Then cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Next cell
    End If
End With
sws.Columns(6).Clear
End Sub
```